# JS Function returns the value before promise resolves

Tags: firebase, functional-programming, firebase-authentication, es6-promise

I want to block the function from returning value before promise resolves. And, pushheaders returns an promise obj instead of just value,

i just want pushheaders to return token which fetched from the firebase

```js
import firebase from 'firebase';

let promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then(token => {
      resolve(token);
    }).catch(err => {
      reject(err)
    });
});


export function pushHeaders (ct) {
  let b = await promise1.then(data => data);
  let headerz = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + b,
  
    }
  }
  ct ? (headerz.headers['Content-Type'] = ct) : null; 
  return headerz;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `await promise1.then(data => data)` is an anti-pattern; replace with `await promise1`

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to synchronize promises so with `await` your function needs to be `async`:

```js
export async function pushHeaders(ct) {
    const token = await promise1; // no need for a noop
    const headers = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            ...(ct ? { 'Content-Type': ct } : {}), // ECMAScript2018
        },
    };
    return headers;
}
```

This also means that it returns a promise and not `headers` directly. To get the actual result you either need to use `then` or use `asycn`/`await` again on the callee.

Comment: Sir, Is there is any other way with which i can get headers directly instead of putting then in callee. Because i have 100s of callee. Changing all would kill time

Comment: @sundar Not really. If you call this 100 places I think your abstractions can be better.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using await, which is a typescript keyword, which is only allowed when you mark your function with Async, try that

```
export async function pushHeaders (ct) {
```

Comment: `async`/`await` is in standard in JS conforming to ECMAScript 2017 and later.

Comment: Thanks, but you just posted an answer that matches mine, where is the value in that?

Comment: My answer mentions elements of you answer, but it does add value as well. Just doing your suggestion doesn't really help alone.

Comment: What else that is needed to be done as well as marking the function as async, that you mentioned and I didn't?

Comment: Well. I mention that he needs to alter the callees since he obviously didn't anticipate it returning promises.